# How to get Google account email address in Google Forms results?

Tags: forms, google-drive-api, google-forms

I am creating a simple form using Google Forms. There are two questions to answer there. One is name and the other one is an option choice question. I am getting result in a spreadsheet. There I can see the time-stamp, name and that question's answer. I have already selected "Can submit only 1 response (requires login)". Now I need to get the email address from where the visitor submitted the form in my result spreadsheet.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried: `Session.getActiveUser()`

Comment: previous comment wont help since its a form. the email will be a sheet column.